# How to upload a file using multipart/related in postman?

Tags: post, file-upload, postman, multipart, onedrive

I want to upload a text file to OneDrive API.I don't have any idea about multipart/related. Can any one suggest me how to put below data in postman to upload a file.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this issue.We need to provide Authorization & Content-Type in header and provide the remaining information in body as raw and select content-type as Text.[image]

[image]